# Is my hosting provider able to see emails sent by my CMS through Gmail SMTP?

Tags: smtp, shared-hosting, whmcs

I wanted to know if the hosting provider can view the emails sent by WHMCS, even if it's using Gmail SMTP.

My WHMCS is on a VPS, and I'm planning to move it to shared hosting. Yet I don't want the hosting provider to be able to access my emails.

Of course, I know that they will be able to access them through the database, but I mean without difficulty and directly.

Comment: Email is not end-to-end encrypted, only the connections between mail servers usually are encrypted. Any participating mail server can read the emails, plus of course the sender and receiver.